# PHP Round in 3s

Tags: php, rounding

I'm getting the time via php

```
$current_hour = date("G");
```

Now let's say the `$current_hour` is equal to 20. How would I round that to 19? Or if `$current_hour` is equal to 00 how would I round that to 22? I don't know if I'm explaining this well, but basically I want to round down each number in intervals of 3 so I get the following:

```
1
4
7
10
13
16
19
22
[back to begining]
```

Any number in between should get rounded to the lowest of them so 11 would be 10, 15 would be 13 and so on...

Comment: sorry my maths isn't that good if that's ment to be simple, or I'm just not seeing it :(

Comment: So, do you want someone to also microwave your dinner while **they** write **your** code? I have confidence that with a little mental application you can figure this problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to use integer operations. First divide by 3, then cast to an int, then multiply by 3 again, with some shifting to preserve the sequence you want.

Example:

```
$current_hour = 20;
echo (intval(($current_hour + 23) / 3) * 3 + 1) % 24; // Outputs 19
```

Comment: I assumed it would be obvious that you add 1 for the offset.. Edited to make it clearer.

Comment: From OP: *I want to round **down** each number in intervals of 3*

Comment: Yeh webbiedave is right, this is nearlly what I would like, but it wont round down

Comment: Thank's, you're a maths genius :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$round = intval(($current_hour - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1;
```

Comment: Also: `if ($current_hour == 0) $current_hour = 24;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$round = (intval(($currentHour + 24) / 3) * 3) % 24 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

```
($current_hour - ($current_hour % 3)) + 1
```